# Why does nuget restore the package ignoring the revision number if it is zero?

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a package added in my project with version `1.0.1.0` but whenever I try to restore this package nuget tries to look for `1.0.1` package ignoring the last zero i.e. revision number?

Why does it do that? and is there any way I can force nuget look for exact and full version of the package while restoring?

Answer (score 0):

Package version are being [normalized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning) since NuGet version >=3.4, on *pack* and *restore*.

> A zero in the fourth part of the version number will be omitted

NuGet now uses [*semantic versioning*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning) and that specifies a fixed format for version numbers.

> A specific version number is in the form Major.Minor.Patch[-Suffix]

The first three parts are mandatory and the suffix is optional.

> - Major: Breaking changes
> - Minor: New features, but backwards compatible
> - Patch: Backwards compatible bug fixes only
> - -Suffix (optional): a hyphen followed by a string denoting a pre-release version [...]

This differs from the .NET [assembly versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyname.version?view=netcore-3.1) scheme that you are used to. Since this versioning scheme is incompatible with NuGet's semantic versioning, the last number is omitted as stated above depending on the NuGet version that your tooling implements.

For example, in Visual Studio 2019, if you have multiple versions `1.0.1.0`, `1.0.1.1`, `1.0.1.42` they will all be listed and you can install a specific version. However, the trailing revision number is ignored if it is `0`, even when you build your own package it will not be appended.

> For packages already built, this normalization does not affect the version numbers in the packages themselves; it affects only how NuGet matches versions when resolving dependencies.

Consequently, if you only *consume* the package and cannot change it, then ignore it. However, if you build the package yourself, you should switch to semantic versioning and consolidate the build and revision numbers to a single `Patch` number or use a suffix like `1.0.1-pre1` if it is only intended for pre-release packages.